# Extract frames from multiple videos into multiple folders

Tags: python, opencv, glob, video-capture

I want to extract frames at every *N* seconds from 3 videos (i.e., **vid1.flv**, **vid2.flv** & **vid3.flv**) and save those corresponding frames to their specific folders (where the folder name is the video name, i.e., **vid1**, **vid2** & **vid3**). How can I do that?

Currently, I can only extract the frames for only one video, and here is my code for one video:

```
import cv2
import os
import logging


def read_video(input_filename):
    return cv2.VideoCapture(input_filename)


def save_frame(count, sec, vid_cap, output_directory):
    vid_cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, sec * 1000)
    hasFrames, frame = vid_cap.read()

    if hasFrames:
        name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), output_directory, "frame" + str(count) + ".png")
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    return hasFrames


def get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, frameRate):
    """
    Capture images from a video at every (i.e, 5 sec, 5 mn, etc.)
    :param frameRate: time we want to capture the images, in seconds.
    """
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
            os.makedirs(output_directory)
    except OSError:
        logging.error('Error creating directory')

    sec = 0
    count = 1
    vid_cap = read_video(input_filename)
    success = save_frame(count, sec, vid_cap, output_directory)

    while success:
        count += 1
        sec = sec + frameRate
        sec = round(sec, 2)
        success = save_frame(count, sec, vid_cap, output_directory)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_filename = 'videos/vid1.flv'
    output_directory = 'frames'
    seconds = 30

    get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to replace:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_filename = 'videos/01_123.flv'
    output_directory = 'frames'
    seconds = 30

    get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, seconds)
```

with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_filename = 'videos/01_123.flv'
    output_directory = 'frames01'
    seconds = 30

    get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, seconds)

    input_filename = 'videos/02_123.flv'
    output_directory = 'frames02'
    seconds = 30

    get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, seconds)
```

Copy/paste is your friend to add more videos if you need to.

---

if you feel adventurous, you may even try to create a loop:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for num in range(3) :
        input_filename = 'videos/%02d_123.flv' % (num+1)
        output_directory = 'frames%02d' % (num+1)
        seconds = 30

        get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, seconds)
```

---

finally, you may automatically loop over the existing videos:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root, dirs, files = os.walk( 'videos' ).next()
    for f in files :
        input_filename = os.path.join( root, f )
        output_directory = f.split('.')[0]
        seconds = 30
        get_frames(input_filename, output_directory, seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it automatically, not manually since I have many videos. I only put 3 as an example. Do you know how to do this? For example, by using glob or something else.

Comment: @belle check the second part of the answer, you may set `range(3)` to `range(100)` if you like

Comment: @belle check the updated anwer. hopefully, this answers all your questions

Comment: @belle again, I have already updated the answer. the last version does not care if the names are continuous or whatever

Comment: The name of each video is not continuous. Please check my updates. 
Can the last choice solve this problem?

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you, i will try it.

Comment: Hi @lenik, it works. However, I got too many frames for the 1st video. Its length is 29mn 17sec, and I got 879 frames. Since I set `seconds=60`, it should give me 29 or 30 frames. Anyway, the 2nd and 3rd videos got the right number of frames. Would you mind check my code for this a little bit? Sorry for disturbing you.